# Left join unexpected results all dates, for all items count

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am writing a report, where basically I would like to return all dates, for all schools, that have or don't have bookings.

Usually I would do it with a left join and one subquery for every level of data that I need.

The case is that it is not working as expected, and I am not sure if I may be missing something or what, but after hours of testing I decided to ask for help!

Here is the fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e9279/5

The expected results should be:

```
on_date     school_name     COALESCE(xx.cnt,0)
2016-02-01  school 1    1
2016-02-01  school 2    0
2016-02-01  school 3    0
2016-02-01  school 4    0
2016-02-01  school 5    0
2016-02-02  school 1    0
2016-02-02  school 2    0
2016-02-02  school 3    0
2016-02-02  school 4    0
2016-02-02  school 5    0
2016-02-03  school 1    0
2016-02-03  school 2    1
2016-02-03  school 3    0
2016-02-03  school 4    0
2016-02-03  school 5    0
```

Etc..

But as shown in the fiddle I get something different. For example the school_name should never be null as I get it from a subquery.

This is what I get in sqlfiddle, I have simplified the whole query just to demo the issue.

[image]

Schema to play with:

```
create table tbl_school (
  school_id int auto_increment primary key,
  school_name varchar(255)
  );

create table tbl_school_booking (
    school_booking_id int auto_increment primary key,
    school_id int,
    booked_date date
);

create table tbl_calendar(
 calendar_date date
);

insert into tbl_school (school_name) values ('school 1'),('school 2'),('school 3'),('school 4'),('school 5');
insert into tbl_school_booking (school_id, booked_date) values (1,'2016-02-01'),(2,'2016-02-03'),(3,'2016-02-07');

insert into tbl_calendar (calendar_date) values ('2016-02-01'),('2016-02-02'), ('2016-02-03'),('2016-02-04'), 
('2016-02-05'),('2016-02-06'),('2016-02-07'),('2016-02-08'),('2016-02-09'),('2016-02-10'),('2016-02-11');
```

Query:

```
   select
     c.calendar_date on_date,
     xx.school_name,
     COALESCE(xx.cnt,0)
   from
     tbl_calendar c

   left join (
     select
       s.school_id,
       s.school_name,
       x.booked_date,
       x.cnt
     from tbl_school s
     left join (
         select 
           sb.booked_date,
           count(*) cnt,
           sb.school_id
         from 
           tbl_school_booking sb
         group by
            sb.booked_date, sb.school_id
     ) x on x.school_id = s.school_id
   ) xx on c.calendar_date=xx.booked_date;
```

Comment: You also should post the data in your question, not everyone can navigate links, and links can become obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to calculate all combinations, then you can see what are the dates missing.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e9279/8)**

```
SELECT s.school_id, c.calendar_date, COUNT(b.school_id)
FROM tbl_school s
CROSS JOIN tbl_calendar c
LEFT JOIN tbl_school_booking b
  ON s.school_id  = b.school_id
 AND c.calendar_date = b.booked_date
GROUP BY  s.school_id, c.calendar_date
;
```

Comment: I did not know about cross join, it worked like a charm, I should have asked for help before!

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is the same as `FROM t1, t2` but explicit declaration.